# Why does the push function affects other objects in an array?

Tags: arrays, angularjs

There is a problem in my app: I'm trying to push the note array into the note**s** array, but when the second array is pushed into notes, all objects in the notes are become the same.

This is my angularJS controller:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("noteCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.note = {};
    $scope.notes = [];

    $scope.submit = function() {
        $scope.notes.push($scope.note);
    };    
});
```

Html code:

```
    <div data-ng-controller="noteCtrl">
        <form name="noteForm" data-ng-submit="submit()">
            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 bdr">
                        <input class="full" type="text" name="title" data-ng-model="note.title" placeholder="Note title is required" required />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 bdr">
                        <textarea class="full" name="content" data-ng-model="note.content" placeholder="Input the note content here"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 bdr">
                        <button class="full" type="reset" data-ng-click="">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 bdr">
                        <button class="full" type="button" data-ng-disabled="noteForm.$invalid" data-ng-click="">Save</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 bdr">
                        <button class="full" type="submit" data-ng-disabled="noteForm.$invalid">Publish</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        {{note}}
        {{notes}}
    </div>
```

For example, I push two different object (with different values of course) into the notes. After the second one is pushed into it, the notes would look like this:

```
[{"title":"aaaa","content":"bbbb"},{"title":"aaaa","content":"bbbb"}]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like your `note` is not updated from the view. can you show us the HTML?

Comment: the html code is updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the note should have properties initially and after push it should be reset.

```
app.controller("noteCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.note = { title: "", content: "" };
    $scope.notes = [];

    $scope.submit = function() {
        $scope.notes.push($scope.note);
        $scope.note = { title: "", content: "" };
    };    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

That is for scope of object. you should define object in function body.

```
$scope.submit = function() {
    var note = {"title":"","content":""};
    $scope.notes.push(note);
};
```